# Rails 4 Turbolinks back button and multiple event binding because of pagesCached

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, turbolinks

I bind my events on $(document).on "page:change"... Example of event bind is as follows:

```
$('#groups').on 'click', 'div.group a.edit_group', Groups.edit_show
```

This works fine with user clicking on links...

The problem occurs when user clicks back button and the forward button. "page:change" triggers another event bind so now I have event binded twice (which is a problem whit jquery toggle function). This double binding occurs I guess because of pagesCached just loads cached DOM of the page with already previously binded events on nodes.

I could disable pagesCached, but is there another solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried in page:change?

```
$('#groups').off().on('click', 'div.group a.edit_group', Groups.edit_show);
```